# AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'density'

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to learn how to work with NetworkX and I've ran into a problem.
Although functions for nodes and edges work fine, the ones for whole graph don't, resulting in AttributeError. Am I using them wrong or can you see some other problem?

The first two works but the third doesn't.

```
num_of_nodes = 0
num_of_nodes = graph.number_of_nodes()
print num_of_nodes

num_of_edges = 0
num_of_edges = graph.number_of_edges()
print num_of_edges

density = 0
density = graph.density()
print density
```

Thanks.

---

imports:

```
import networkx as nx
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np
import urllib3
import time
import operator
import socket
import cPickle
import re # regular expressions

from pandas import Series
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: could you post your import statements here as well? many assumptions can be made without that.

Comment: BTW, why do you set `num_of_nodes`, `num_of_edges`and `density` to `0` if you rebind the variables in the following line?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/functions.html), `density()` appears to be a function, not an object method. So you want `density(graph)`. (Caveat: I've not actually used networkx before, I'm just purely going by the docs.)

Comment: @stucash imports added;


Matthias: I'm not sure, I'm trying everything I can think of when something doesn't work. Can it somehow be the reason for not working?


glibdud: I tried it like that as well and still doesn't work, it says TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: From your includes I would assume that you need to use `nx.density(graph)`.

Comment: @vonludi ohhh that's it!!  ok I don't get it why you sometimes need and sometimes you don't but thank you anyway!

Comment: sometimes you can do `G.method()`  and other times `nx.function(G)`.  To some degree, it's simply a question of which the programmers have implemented.  As a general rule with networkx, my experience is that if you expect that something requires a nontrivial calculation, then it's `nx.function(G)`.  If it's something that's more like a property of `G`, then you can do `G.method()` [though I believe `nx.function(G)` would always exist as well].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**(this answer is basically the same as glibdud put in his comment - @glibdud, feel free to add your own version of this answer, and I'll delete mine)

---

So let's look first at `number_of_nodes`.  Here's the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.number_of_nodes.html?highlight=number_of_nodes#networkx.classes.function.number_of_nodes).  You call it like `nx.number_of_nodes(G)`.  If you check the [source](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/classes/function.html#number_of_nodes), it simply calls `G.number_of_nodes()`.  So notice - these are two different things (though they use the same name), and produce the same output.  In one, `G` is the argument of the function `number_of_nodes`, in the other, `number_of_nodes` is a method of `G`.

However, `density` does not exist as a method of `G`.  It is simply a function of networkx.  Here's the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.density.html?highlight=density#networkx.classes.function.density).  You call it like `nx.density(G)`.